# XML Webservice won't handshake with consumer application in same VS2019 solution

Tags: visual-studio-2019, asmx, webservice-client

My VS2019 web service app solution cannot connect a client app to the .asmx web service within the same solution, if I close and re-open Visual Studio.  I need help figuring out why the connection is being "forcibly rejected".
This xml web service (.asmx) has been in production for years.  The code is in a VS2019 solution on my desktop that also contains a desktop application that consumes the web service for testing.  I added another .asmx page, added a web reference to, tested, everything is fine.  The in-solution web reference url is "http://localhost:3455/Mobility20.asmx".
But then I saved everything, closed Visual Studio, and opened it again.  Now my test app fails to connect to either local web reference with:

```
System.Net.WebException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:3455
```

But I can still connect to and use the production-deployed instance of the web service.

I've tried:

- Backing my code out to the last git commit and starting over.  Same thing.
- Setting TLS settings to 'best practice' with CryptoIIS.
- http and https (each time making sure everything in the solution matches)
- Checking the firewall that it is not blocking my port 3455
- Turning off 'edit and continue' (that I read somewhere)

Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot this?